# How was iī pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation, vowel-quantity, vowel, ending, phonology

Most of the time, Latin doesn't allow two instances of the same vowel next to each other: forms like **mee* (from *meus*) are replaced with alternatives like *mī*.

However, in I-stem second nouns, the combination *iī* can occur (for example, *filiī* "sons"). Do we know how this was pronounced? Was there a consonant separating the two vowels, or did they merge into an extra-long *i*, or did the quality difference between the two vowels keep them apart?

I'm most interested in Classical pronunciation, but anything pre-Ecclesiastic is relevant!

(Related: [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5201/how-was-vv-pronounced) covers *uu*, and the accepted answer mentions that a vowel before another vowel seems to have become long-like in quality, but doesn't cover groups like *iī* where the second vowel is long by nature.)

Comment: I bet your answer is in verse... metrics!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think we can know for certain, but the fact that the spelling "filii" occurred makes it likely that the word was *perceived* as having three syllables, and was so treated in poetry.  There are various possibilities of how it was actually pronounced:

1)  A single extra-long vowel, [i::], in which case the spelling represents perception only.

2)  It's possible there may have occurred some subphonemic glide between the vowels, such as [iji:], or (less likely in my opinion) a subphonemic glottal stop, [iʔi:].

3)  It's possible there may have been some tonal difference between the two syllables.

4)  There's also the fact that short /i/ is generally thought to have had a relatively open pronunciation, i.e., [ɪ], so the pronunciation [ɪi:] may have been the case.  (Of course, [ɪ] may have been used in possibilities (2) and (3) above, too.)

I don't think it's possible to know which of these was the case, lacking the evidence of a trained phonetician in Roman times or a time machine.  But, I think these are all possibilities.

Comment: There seems to be less certainty about the pronunciation of short /i/ as /ɪ/ when it comes before another vowel, though. There are words in some Romance languages that seem to show reflexes of Latin [ɪ] > [e]  (e.g. French "voie", from Latin "via"), but if I remember correctly, there are also words that seem to show the reflex of Latin [i] (I know of an old article that talks about this, "[Hiatus and Vocalic Quality in Classical and Vulgar Latin](https://www.jstor.org/stable/267006?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)" by
G. K. Meadows (1946), but I forget any specific examples)

Comment: Allen also talks about this issue; I give the relevant quote in my answer here: https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/1072/9

Comment: So, the take-home message (for everyone) is we don't know for sure - and most likely never will - and we shouldn't really worry about it.